An explicit axiomatization of the theory of the class of all $Z_n$
Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider the set $Z_n := \{0,...,n-1\}$, under the operations $+$ and $\times$ of addition modulo $n$ and multiplication modulo $n$, respectively. Consider the class (in fact, the set) $K$ of all $\{+,\times\}$-structures $Z_n$, as $n$ runs through every positive integer. Now, by the compactness theorem, I know that $K$ is not first-order axiomatizable, even up to isomorphism. However, $K$ does have an associated first-order theory $Th(K)$. My main question is, is $Th(K)$ finitely axiomatizable, or at least recursively axiomatizable? If either, can someone give an explicit presentation of a set of axioms for $Th(K)$?

In very recent work, Derakhshan and Macintyre have shown that $\mathrm{Th}(K)$ is decidable. This answers a question of Ax from 1968.
Since every decidable theory $T$ is recursively axiomatizable (simply list all sentences, and take as axioms all those which are in $T$), it follows that your theory is recursively axiomatizable. However, my understanding is that Derakhshan and Macintyre do not give a really explicit axiomatization.

But is it, in fact, finitely axiomatizable? Or is that still not known?

I highly doubt it is finitely axiomatizable, but I don't know how to prove this. @user107952
